# Docker rails neither gem install nor bundle install installs gem correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I tried installing the gravtastic gem and what I did was the following:

1. put `gem 'gravtastic'` in the Gemfile
2. run `sudo docker-compose run web bundle install`

   The output of this includes gravtastic
3. run `sudo docker-compose up`

I have tried running `sudo docker-compose run web gem install gravtastic` but with no result

When i run `gem list` gravtastic is not listed

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this was resolved by rebuilding the docker image

```
sudo docker-compose build
```

Comment: is there any way to not have to rebuild the whole image each time?

Comment: While this was a long time ago I think the image only needed to be rebuilt once. You can build a single container by adding argument -d <container-name> to the Docker-compose command